# Inserting and formatting text in existing placeholder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-pptx

I have a slide template that has a text placeholder. How do I insert and format text in that specific text placeholder ?

```
text_ph1 = slide1.placeholders[14]
text_ph2 = slide1.placeholders[15]

para1 = ['Text for para 1']
para2 = ['Text for para 2']

p = text_ph1.paragraphs[0]
run = p.add_run()
run.text = para1[0]

font = run.font
font.name = 'Calibri'
font.size = Pt(14)
font.bold = False
font.italic = None
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-205-ce3eb19a0d8b> in <module>
      2 text_frame.clear()  # not necessary for newly-created shape
      3 
----> 4 p = text_ph1.paragraphs[0]
      5 run = p.add_run()
      6 run.text = para1[0]

AttributeError: 'SlidePlaceholder' object has no attribute 'paragraphs'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A placeholder is a shape, mostly like any other auto-shape (rectangle, text-box, circle, etc.).

To access the text of the shape, use its `.text_frame` property to retrieve its `TextFrame` object. The `TextFrame` object has the paragraphs (not the shape directly) so something like this should work:

```
text_ph1 = slide1.placeholders[14]
text_ph1.text_frame.text = "Text for para 1"
```

If you then want to format the text you added, you'll find it in the first run of the first paragraph:

```
font = text_ph1.text_frame.paragraphs[0].runs[0].font
font.name = 'Calibri'
font.size = Pt(14)
font.bold = False
font.italic = False
```

Comment: Thanks @scanny . This worked. You should include these as tips on the tutorials page.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Pawan_Malviya, glad you got it working :) Don't neglect to accept this answer if it answered your question. That's how the StackOverflow economy works :)

Answer (score -1):

Hope I understood your question.

example:

```py
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation()
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title
subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]

title.text = "Text for para 1"
subtitle.text = "Text for para 2"

prs.save('test.pptx')
```

Comment: I don't need it for the title slide . That is generic. I need it for another layout